# AmazonS3Exception: x-amz-website-redirect-location header is not supported for this operation

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have got an interesting exception when trying to upload data from Android client to AWS:

```
com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: x-amz-website-redirect-location header is not supported for this operation. (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidArgument; Request ID: E3900749ACF1D979), S3 Extended Request ID: kFjMM7JVFSOxvaKlHgM0bVM5zKZAR/0K8qeMyt44vjvtMFcGk8CxY9gDBDs0sqWmr8r2jcCyENo=
```

The user located in China region and data is uploaded it `under VPN` (HongKong) to western bucket `http://currentidmedia.s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com`

More details about request below:

```
PUT http://currentidmedia.s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com / Headers: (Expect: 100-continue, Content-Type: application/octet-stream, Date: Fri, 05 Jun 2015 10:13:01 GMT+00:00, Content-Length: 0, User-Agent: aws-sdk-android/2.2.1 Linux/3.4.0-g8a80a0e Dalvik/2.1.0/0 en_US com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.s3.transfermanager.TransferManager/2.2.1, x-amz-website-redirect-location: /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20150601_153423.jpg, Accept-Encoding: identity, Authorization: AWS AKIAIYL3TJHYVMB4SFRQ:dAkmOJxaIe5viO5kNjz74I/UKSc=, )
```

Does it bug in SDk or I don't use it in proper way?

UPDATE:

```
// set up credentials
AWSCredentials awsCredentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(
        awsMetadata.getAccountId(),
        awsMetadata.getSecretKey()
);
// set up request
PutObjectRequest request = new PutObjectRequest(
        awsMetadata.getBucketName(),
        FileUtil.extractNameFromPath(mediaItem.getContentUri()),
        mediaItem.getContentUri()
);
// perform request
TransferManager transferManager = new TransferManager(awsCredentials);
transferManager.getAmazonS3Client().setRegion(getRegionForMedia(awsMetadata));
transferManager.upload(request, listener);
```

The answer is I used PutObjectRequest in not correct way. It contains several constructors and if you pass String to content instead of File you setup redirection url instead of path to the data.

However after fix I got the same `SSLException` error for non-China bucket. I used it under `VPN` and without it. More details about request you can find below.

```
PUT https://currentidmedia.s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com / Headers: (Content-MD5: GI1M/hfrwwQHvHMBlmh/lA==, Expect: 100-continue, Content-Type: image/jpeg, Date: Sat, 06 Jun 2015 08:56:31 GMT+00:00, Content-Length: 2140572, User-Agent: aws-sdk-android/2.2.1 Linux/3.4.0-g8a80a0e Dalvik/2.1.0/0 en_US com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.s3.transfermanager.TransferManager/2.2.1, Accept-Encoding: identity, Authorization: AWS AKIAIYL3TJHYVMB4SFRQ:fqWbHO6lBPsbI6lkcaHKhms8Hkw=, )
```

Comment: Would you please provide your code snippet so that I have more context about the error? In particular, I am curious about how you construct the transfer manager (or s3 client), in which region, and object metadata your pass in.

Comment: That's odd, because I don't see where you set the header x-amz-website-redirect-location. Do you mind sharing the stacktrace?

Comment: I use this region endpoint "RegionEndpoint":"ap-southeast-1". Metadata contains secret key and account id which acts as accessId. I receive this fomr our server which also used by iOS client and iOS client works well for  China and non-China regions as well

Comment: Yangfan, I dont setup this header so I surpised to see it in exception from SDK. This code above covers all steps which I operate to upload file

Comment: I can't answer your question without reproducing it myself. One last question, have you tried this sample https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-android-samples/tree/master/S3_TransferManager? Modify it to use your credentials and change the region to ap-southeast-1.

Comment: As your test sample -- I don't have an amazon account to use cognito pool. For our product we have our server which acts as mediator between our clients and aws which provide us credentials

Comment: Sorry I don't have joinme. That'll be a little difficult to test. I can't say for sure whether it's an SDK bug or some service restriction. I'll ping S3 (expect 1-2 business days).

Comment: I update the original post. I didn't use SDK correctly this time. However after fix non-China bucket produces the same error as for China region

Comment: Awesome. The fix for signing issue should be out soon. Stay tuned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `x-amz-website-redirect-location` metadata is for static website only. Static website has a different endpoint `<bucket-name>.s3-website-<AWS-region>.amazonaws.com`. See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/WebsiteHosting.html for more information. Do you mind explaining the purpose of setting it? I'll see if there is an alternative.

Comment: Yes, but no.  This header impacts *behavior* of the web site endpoint, but it's still *uploaded* to the REST endpoint.