# Upload to pre-signed S3 URL fails with OkHttp

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, okhttp

I am getting an SSL exception when I try to upload a file to Amazon S3's pre-signed URL with OkHttp 3.9.1: `SSLException: Write error: ssl=0xa0b73280: I/O error during system call, Connection reset by peer`

It is the same problem as in [another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36545521/i-o-error-during-system-call-connection-reset-by-peer-issue-with-s3-client/48503726) but in my case it fails always. I upload just files over 1MiB in size, I have not tried small files.

As I mentioned in my answer in that question, switching to Java's `HttpURLConnection` fixed the problem and the upload works perfectly.

Here is my `RequestBody` implementation (in Kotlin) to upload a file from Android's `Uri` and I do use OkHttp's `.put()` method:

```
class UriRequestBody(private val file: Uri, private val contentResolver: ContentResolver, private val mediaType: MediaType = MediaType.parse("application/octet-stream")!!): RequestBody() {
    override fun contentLength(): Long = -1L

    override fun contentType(): MediaType? = mediaType

    override fun writeTo(sink: BufferedSink) {
        Okio.source((contentResolver.openInputStream(file))).use {
            sink.writeAll(it)
        }
    }
}
```

and here is my `HttpURLConnection` implementation:

```
private fun uploadFileRaw(file: Uri, uploadUrl: String, contentResolver: ContentResolver) : Int {
    val url = URL(uploadUrl)
    val connection = url.openConnection() as HttpURLConnection
    connection.doOutput = true
    connection.requestMethod = "PUT"
    val out = connection.outputStream

    contentResolver.openInputStream(file).use {
        it.copyTo(out)
    }

    out.close()
    return connection.responseCode
}
```

What is OkHttp doing differently so it can lead to this SSL exception?

**EDIT:**

Here is the OkHttp code to upload the file (using the default `application/octet-stream` mime type):

```
val s3UploadClient = OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
    .connectTimeout(30_000L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
    .readTimeout(30_000L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
    .writeTimeout(60_000L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
    .retryOnConnectionFailure(true)
    .build()

val body: RequestBody = UriRequestBody(file, contentResolver)
val request = Request.Builder()
        .url(uploadUrl)
        .put(body)
        .build()

s3UploadClient.newCall(request).execute()
```

And this is the JavaScript server code that generates the pre-signed upload URL:

```
const s3 = new aws.S3({
    region: 'us-west-2',
     signatureVersion: 'v4'
});
const signedUrlExpireSeconds = 60 * 5;

const signedUrl = s3.getSignedUrl('putObject', {
    Bucket: config.bucket.name,
    Key: `${fileName}`,
    Expires: signedUrlExpireSeconds
});
```

Answer (score 3):

This seems to work with retrofit library:

```
fun uploadImage(imagePath: String, directUrl: String): Boolean {
    Log.d(TAG, "Image: ${imagePath}, Url: $directUrl")
    val request = Request.Builder()
            .url(directUrl)
            .put(RequestBody.create(null, File(imagePath)))
            .build()
    val response = WebClient.getOkHttpClient().newCall(request).execute()
    return response.isSuccessful
}
```